# How to use cookies in JavaScript to remember if user has clicked 'don't show me this again'

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have created a pop up dialog box that prompts users to either visit our Facebook, Twitter or just click 'don't show me this again'

I am only implementing this for a short period of time for it doesn't become too annoying, but I don't want it to pop up every time they refresh the page.

I have looked at cookies with JavaScript but i can't seem to get it to work with my code.

My JS code looks like this:

```
    function popUp(div){
document.getElementById(div).style.display='block';
return false;
}
function hide(div){
document.getElementById(div).style.display='none';
return false;
}
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
<body onLoad="return popUp('pop')">

    <div id="pop" class="disableBackground">
        <div id="popup">
        <h1 title="Social">You can also find us here</h1>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        <br />
        <a class="btn-connect-option facebook badge-facebook-connect" href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
        <a class="btn-connect-option twitter" href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <p onClick="return hide('pop')" style="cursor: pointer">Don't show me this again</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I am not expecting you to code my needs, I would just really appreciate some guidance on how to achieve this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want help with cookies, you should post your cookie code that's not working. That said, working with cookies is a bit unintuitive and a small wrapper can help. If you are using jQuery: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie or http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script (whole article is worth reading) for vanilla JS.

Comment: @TimMedora Sorry, I usually would add my attempted code but I deleted it after trying everything I could for I could have a clean try again but it just wouldn't work. Thanks a lot for the info though!

Comment: I agree with @TimMedora cookies are a bit of a pain and the https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie plugin for jquery works magic.

Answer (score 0):

If we [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+setcookie+getcookie+is%3Aanswer) for answers in the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag that contain `getcookie` and `setcookie` there are enough results to build our functions:

> [image]

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var our_cookie_name = 'popupdiv';
    function popUp( div ) {
        if( getCookie( our_cookie_name ) != div )
            document.getElementById(div).style.display='block';
        return false;
    }
    function hide( div ) {
        setCookie( our_cookie_name, div );
        document.getElementById(div).style.display='none';
        return false;
    }
    function setCookie( name, value, days ) {
        var expires = "";
        if ( days ) {
            var date = new Date(); 
            date.setTime( date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000) );
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    } 
    function getCookie( name ) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(";");
        for( var i=0; i < ca.length; i++ ) {
            var c = ca[i]; 
            while ( c.charAt(0) == ' ' ) 
                c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if ( c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0 ) 
                return c.substring( nameEQ.length, c.length );
        }
        return null;
    }
    function eraseCookie( name ) {
        setCookie( name, "", -1 );
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="popUp('popup-container')">
<small><a href="javascript:eraseCookie(our_cookie_name)">Clear cookie</a></small>
<hr />
<div id="popup-container" class="disableBackground" style="display:none">
    <div id="popup">
        <h1 title="Social">You can also find us here</h1>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        <br />
        <a class="btn-connect-option facebook badge-facebook-connect" href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
        <a class="btn-connect-option twitter" href="http://twitter.com/" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <p onClick="return hide('popup-container')" style="cursor: pointer">Don't show me this again</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

With these two function you can set a new cookie, and get the value of a set cookie(or check if a cookie is set). Set your desired cookie in the hide() function, and check for it in the pop function, before you show the div. You can find these functions, and explanations to them here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
 var exdate=new Date();
 exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
 var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
 document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
 var c_value = document.cookie;
 var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
 if (c_start == -1)
 {
   c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
 }
 if (c_start == -1)
 {
  c_value = null;
 }
 else
 {
   c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
   var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
   if (c_end == -1)
 {
   c_end = c_value.length;
 }
   c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
 }
 return c_value;
}
```